# How can Dependabot automatically merge its pull requests based on Azure pipelines build status?

Tags: github, git-merge, dependabot, dependabot-script

If Dependabot is enabled to automatically bump dependencies and create pull requests to 'master', how these pull requests can be automated so they are automatically approved and merged if Dependabot's branch passes Azure Devops build pipeline?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I automerge dependabot updates (config version 2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116781/how-do-i-automerge-dependabot-updates-config-version-2)