# How do I automerge dependabot updates (config version 2)?

Tags: python, github, yaml, github-actions, dependabot

Following "Dependabot is moving natively into GitHub!", I had to update my dependabot config files to use version 2 format.

My *.dependabot/config.yaml* did look like:

```yaml
version: 1
update_configs:
  - package_manager: "python"
    directory: "/"
    update_schedule: "live"
    automerged_updates:
      - match:
          dependency_type: "all"
          update_type: "all"
```

I've got the following working:

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
- package-ecosystem: pip
  directory: "/"
  schedule:
    interval: daily
```

but I can't seem to add the automerge option again (when checking with the [dependabot validator](https://dependabot.com/docs/config-file/validator))?

Comment: Sounds like they may be holding off this feature for now: https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/1973

Comment: You should add this as an answer

Comment: Besides, just a heads up, this feature will never be added to Dependabot on GitHub. Check the answer by @milton-castro

Comment: Looks like GitHub does not intend to add it as a feature _directly_ to Dependabot, but they nevertheless have officially documented how to do it with an [Actions workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68365564/418413).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is one solution that doesn't require any additional marketplace installations (originally found [here](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/1973#issuecomment-701889737)). Simply create a new GitHub workflow (e.g. `.github/workflows/dependabotautomerge.yml`) containing:

```yaml
name: "Dependabot Automerge - Action"

on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  worker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    if: github.actor == 'dependabot[bot]'
    steps:
      - name: automerge
        uses: actions/github-script@0.2.0
        with:
          script: |
            github.pullRequests.createReview({
              owner: context.payload.repository.owner.login,
              repo: context.payload.repository.name,
              pull_number: context.payload.pull_request.number,
              event: 'APPROVE'
            })
            github.pullRequests.merge({
              owner: context.payload.repository.owner.login,
              repo: context.payload.repository.name,
              pull_number: context.payload.pull_request.number
            })
          github-token: ${{github.token}}
```

There are also various third-party solutions available on [GitHub Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?query=dependabot+merge).

Comment: That code snippet should be credited. Here's the original source: https://secopslab.medium.com/automerge-github-dependabot-alerts-with-github-actions-7cd6f5763750

Comment: Is that the original source for the officially-documented approach? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68365564/418413

Comment: (Probably not, since the officially documented approach is substantially different.)

Answer (score 14):

This is now an [officially documented feature](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/keeping-your-dependencies-updated-automatically/automating-dependabot-with-github-actions#approve-a-pull-request). You can approve a Dependabot pull request and set it to auto-merge with a GitHub Actions workflow like…

```yaml
name: Dependabot auto-approve
on: pull_request_target
    
permissions:
  contents: write
  pull-requests: write
    
jobs:
  dependabot:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.actor == 'dependabot[bot]' }}
    steps:
      - name: Dependabot metadata
        id: metadata
        uses: dependabot/fetch-metadata@v1.1.1
        with:
          github-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
      - name: Enable auto-merge for Dependabot PRs
        if: ${{contains(steps.metadata.outputs.dependency-names, 'my-dependency') && steps.metadata.outputs.update-type == 'version-update:semver-patch'}}
        run: gh pr merge --auto --merge "$PR_URL"
        env:
          PR_URL: ${{github.event.pull_request.html_url}}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

#### Update: CODEOWNERS does allow negation after all

If you use [code owners](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-on-github/about-code-owners) and the branch is protected, you may find this will still wait for code owner review to merge. You can require codeowner review for all but the relevant files with a `.github/CODEOWNERS` file something like this:

```
* owner1 owner2 @org/team1
setup.cfg  # setup.cfg is not owned
```

Comment: Two caveats: 1. You have to enable auto-merge in your repo settings, 2. You have to protect the target branch with “checks must pass before merge”. If you don’t do both of these the command line above (for some reason) merges the PR as soon as it runs 

Comment: @mxcl The workflow can be ordered and set up dependencies. Assume there is a build and automerge workflow, you can set the automerge run after build workflow result is successful.

Comment: @mxcl Could you please provide a link to a documentation or implementation of the to how "toprotect the target branch with “checks must pass before merge”?

Comment: They're tucked away under a feature called "protected branches". https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#require-status-checks-before-merging

Comment: One can use [github-action-wait-for-status](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/github-action-wait-for-status#github-action-wait-for-status) if one does not want to play around with required status checks.

Comment: Instead of merging it yourself you can just add the comment `@dependabot merge` and dependabot will do it for you once all the status checks are satisfied.

Answer (score 10):

Auto-merge was disabled on the Dependabot into GitHub:

> Auto-merge will not be supported in GitHub-native Dependabot for the foreseeable future. We know some of you have built great workflows that rely on auto-merge, but right now, we’re concerned about auto-merge being used to quickly propagate a malicious package across the ecosystem. We recommend always verifying your dependencies before merging them.

There are some hacks to accomplish this job, you can check GitHub `dependabot-core` [issue #1973](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/1973) for some ideas.